# SQL error while using limit keyword in Derby

Tags: sql, derby

I have used limit keyword as:

```
"select * from empl3 limit "+4
```

But I am getting the error as:

> Syntax error: Encountered "4" at line 1, column 27.

I am using Derby database.

Comment: Where in the [Derby manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/index.html) did you find `LIMIT`?

Answer (score 8):

[As documented in the manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqlj41360.html) there is no `LIMIT` clause in Derby.

Derby uses the SQL standard for limiting the number of rows:

```
select * 
from empl3 
fetch first 4 rows only;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the +4 after the select statement is giving you the error. You should return all of your data necessary for you page `select * from empl3`, but handle the paging in your page itself.

Comment: I didn't realize this was Derby when I first answered this. Look at @a_horse_with_no_name answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key is in your words *I am using derby database* - see [Does Derby support a LIMIT command](http://db.apache.org/derby/faq.html#limit).

You can either use the workaround suggested in the linked FAQ, or implement paging on your own, as suggested by WEI_DBA.

Comment: Derby's FAQ is a bit outdated. They support "fetch first x rows" since 10.5